# Xamarin SignaturePad Proper way of using UWP GetImageAsync?

Tags: xamarin

I'm using xamarin SignaturePad.

How to use GetImageAsync properly? because the output is not the same with my input.

I use this code:

```
var imageStream = await signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg);

public static byte[] ConvertStreamToByte(Stream stream)
{
        if (stream != null)
        {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                      stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                      return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
        }

        return null;
}
```

Convert Byte[] to Image.

```
this.SignatureImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(signatureData.Data));
```

[image: My input:]

[image: Result:]

My input on top.

Bottom pic is the retrieved data.

Is it misuse of GetImageAsync or Wrong Conversion? Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var imageStream = await signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg 
, Color.Black, Color.White);

Need to add color for stroke and backround else it will default to black.